# Bundle Python app without interpreter

Tags: python, bundle, interpreter, distribute

I have a Python script with just minimal import (=psutil) and have  bundled it with py2app. However, the resulting app is almost 9 MB because it includes the interpreter. I am looking for ways to reduce the size - the best way I can think of is to exclude the interpreter from the bundle and let the app use the client's native interpreter. Right now I am doing it only for Mac but will need to do it for all platforms. I have looked at squeeze ( http://effbot.org/zone/squeeze.htm ) but it seems to have little or no docs! - for installing, using it?

Comment: If you want to do it for all platforms, how will "native interpreter" work with Windows?

Comment: I'll use a PC instead of the mac to bundle the app.