# Bundle Python app without interpreter-part 2

Tags: python, size, bundle, executable

I have asked this question earlier - [Bundle Python app without interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538153/bundle-python-app-without-interpreter) but I wasn't very clear on how to go about it. The question is - I have developed bundles for all 3 major platforms using py2app - Mac, bbfreeze - CentOS, pyinstaller - windows. However, I all the bundles wrap the python interpreter in it. The resulting size is approx. 8-10 MB. I need to find a way to bundle my app in a smaller size and the best I can think of is to exclude the interpreter and let the executable use the client's own Python. Of course, the bundle should include the Python (3rd party) modules that constitute the app's dependencies. Thanks,

Comment: What will you do if any of the app's dependencies require a different version of Python than the client's own Python?  It seems like you lose most of the point of bundling if you allow the possibility that the user might have to install a whole new version of Python separate from your bundle.

Comment: I am assuming that most clients will have v2.4+ and the dependencies are fine with that. For few that don't, the interpreter will have to be included.

Comment: Why are you making an executable if you dont want to include he interpreter? Then you are better off just creating a batch script.

Comment: Thx. I am reading up on batch scripts. However, there are some values required by the script that I need to put in a properties file that the script will import + readme, license, etc. files.